# How to use EntityManager as a service?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I use Doctrine and try to use [DependencyInjection Component][1] without Symfony (outside of a Symfony application).
I have [bootstrap.php for doctrine][2]:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$isDevMode = false;
$paths = ["src/Project/Infrastructure/Persistence/Doctrine/Mapping/"];
$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);

$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'dbname'   => 'project',
);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

And I have a file to configure the container:

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new XmlFileLoader($containerBuilder, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/services.xml');
```

And I want to get EntityManager from container such as:
`$entityManager = $containerBuilder->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getManager();`

But what should I do here I don't understand:

```
  //config/services.xml
  <services>
        <defaults autowire="true" autoconfigure="true"/>
        <service id="Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface" alias="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" public="false" />
    </services>
```

How I can register EntityManager as a service? (I don't use Symfony just DI component)
[1]: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html
[2]: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager

Comment: You could check the DependencyInjection directory in the DoctrineBundle. Since you already configured Doctrine outside the symfony container, you could just inject it as a _synthetic_ service: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/synthetic_services.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a 'how do I use the DI component without reading the documentation' sort of question.  But it is kind of interesting so here are some hints.

You need to configure a Doctrine configuration service and then inject it into the entity manager service.  Both services use a static factory method so something like:

```
parameters:
    isDevMode: true

services:
    doctrine.orm.config:
        public: false
        class: 'Doctrine\ORM\Configuration'
        factory: 
            - 'Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup'
            - 'createYAMLMetadataConfiguration'
        arguments:
            - ['src/Entity'] 
            - '%isDevMode%'

    doctrine.orm.entity_manager:
        public: true
        class: 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'
        factory:
              - 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'
              - 'create'
        arguments:
            -
              driver:  'pdo_mysql'
              user:     db_user
              password: db_password
              dbname:   db_name
            - '@doctrine.orm.config'
```

I used yaml here because it's easier for me to understand.  You of course can convert to xml.  You never want to check in your database credentials but I'll leave that for the student to figure out.  This is the sort of thing that the Doctrine bundle deals with and is why you should probably use the framework.

The test application looks like:

```
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
$loader->load('config/services.yaml');

$container->compile();

$em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

echo get_class($em) . "\n";
```

I tested it and it all works.

Enjoy.

Comment: This is working so far, but as soon as I try to fetch entities from the database, I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: No mapping file found named 'App.Entity.User.dcm.yml' for class 'App\Entity\User'. in /var/www/html/awsconnect/awsconnect_FRS/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:65
```

Doctrine doesn't seem to know about my Symfony entities.

Comment: You probably need to adjust the src/Entity to point to the directory where your mapping files live.  Follow the examples in the Doctrine docs.  Mapping files are usually in their own directory.

Comment: Oh, I completly overread that this solution does not use Symfony, I'm sorry! I've changed `createYAMLMetadataConfiguration` to `createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration` but now I'm facing new problems. I guess I will try a different approach.